# WebClient not working when service run as LocalService Account

Tags: c#, http, service, user-accounts

I have a Windows Service that sends a Post Request to a url:

```
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(url, myParameters);

                Console.WriteLine(HtmlResult);
            }
```

This works only if  the Service is run As Administrator and when run in a console application. When run as LocalService Account i get a Timeout.

What can i do about this?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess your problem is that a localservice is not allowed to access remote resources. Thus you need to use an account that is allowed to use remote resources like network service or a user account created with specific rights that fit your needs (you might also need to access a local folder to read/write data) which is the best practice imho.

Answer (score 0):

Once running a network-related code under LocalService account, you're appearing as anonymous user. So it's quite likely that guest access is disabled on to your premises. So it's may be worth to replace LocalService with NetworkService (which is specially designed for network staff). http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/understanding-local-service-and-network-service-accounts